# scons - running program after compilation

Tags: c++, python, scons

I want to run the built program directly after compilation, so that i can build and start my program with `scons`.

I thought that this SConstruct-File, would start the program, whenever it is rebuilt.

```
main = Program( "main", [ "main.cc" ] )

test = Command( None, None, "./main >testoutput" )
Depends( test, main )
```

And this would start it, every time I run `scons`

```
main = Program( "main", [ "main.cc" ] )

test = Command( None, None, "./main >testoutput" )
Requires( test, main )
```

But both don't work, my program is never executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work better to run the program only when its built.

```
main = Program( "main", [ "main.cc" ] )

test = Command( target = "testoutput",
                source = "./main",
                action = "./main > $TARGET" )
Depends( test, main )
```

And use the AlwaysBuild() to run it every time, as mentioned by @doublep like this:

```
main = Program( "main", [ "main.cc" ] )

test = Command( target = "testoutput",
                source = "./main",
                action = "./main > $TARGET" )
AlwaysBuild( test )
```

And if you want to see the contents of the testoutput, you could do this:

(Assuming Linux. It would be more portable to print the file with some Python code instead)

```
main = Program( "main", [ "main.cc" ] )

test = Command( target = "testoutput",
                source = "./main",
                action = ["./main > $TARGET",
                          "cat $TARGET"] )
AlwaysBuild( test )
```

Comment: When I use `#` in action and source, testoutput isn't generated any more. scons prints `#/main > testoutput` but `testoutput` doesn't exist and so prints this line always. Is there a way to have this, without writing this to testoutput instead to stdout? I want to see the results immediately and don't want to look into this file.

Comment: @dinfuehr, I wont be able to test this until tomorrow morning. Does my solution work for you using "./main" with out the "#"? I dont understand your question about stdout.

Comment: Yes, without # it works. I wanted to know if it's possible, to have the action like "./main" only (without the "> $TARGET") so that I see the output of the program directly when calling scons, without having to inspect the output file.

Comment: @dinfuehr, I would have to test that, but try using `action="./main"` and `target=None`. Doing so may make the dependency checking not work in the first example (with the Depends) and possibly in the seconds example. I'll update the answer with a better alternative.

Comment: @dinfuehr, I was able to test this today. The '#' character is better used if you have a variant_dir. Setting the Command() target parameter as None will not work correctly, nor if you set target and source as None. If you want to execute the command after compilation and see the results, the third example in my answer works, whereby I specified a list of actions for the Command() builder. I think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: It seems that a more platform-independent way to write it would be `Command(target = 'dummy', source=str(main[0]), action='$SOURCE')`

Comment: The above doesn't work, but this does: `Command(target=None, source=str(main[0]), action='$SOURCE ')`  Note the space after `$SOURCE` in the `action` string. That makes it work for me. And `target=None` does work.

Comment: For linux, you could use `"$SOURCE | tee $TARGET"` instead of `"./main > $TARGET", "cat $TARGET"` to get output immediately (for long-running programs).

Answer (score 4):

This runs `ls` every time SCons is run:

```
ls = Command ('ls', None, 'ls')
AlwaysBuild ('ls')
Default ('ls')
```

You never told SCons why and when it should run your command.  You should e.g. add it as a dependency to some other target or make it the default target.

If you want to run command *really always*, i.e. regardless of what target is being built, you should probably run it using standard Python facilities for launching external programs.

Comment: How can I run my program only after it was rebuilt? (Always running my program, now works for me)

Comment: Make the command depend on the program.  Then the executable will be rebuilt (if necessary) before being run.  I.e. `x_program = Program ('x', ...); x = Command ('x', None, './x'); Depends ('x', x_program)`

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work for me: `Multiple ways to build the same target were specified for: x`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I specified the same target for the program and command in my example.  I guess you don't actually need target for the command as long as you use Python variables to create dependencies on it.

Comment: But then the code looks exactly like my first example, doesn't it?

Comment: The point is to have `Default(...)` or have some other target depend on the command.  Otherwise SCons won't see why it should run the command at all, as from SCons'es point of view it would serve no purpose.  If you specify a target, command will be used to build that target.  If not, than it will be used only if required as a dependency to some other target.